# Получение и проверка значения атрибута JS -> выполнение операции

Tags: javascript

Необходимо найти значение `data-deadline`, которое равно `48` и если истина, то всю строку `tr` окрасить в красный(допустим).

```html
<table><thead><tbody><tr class="resultTr2" style="background-color: #333" data-deadline="48" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">      
    
  <td> <p>Что-то</p>                                                   </td>
        
 </tr></tbody></thead></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].dataset.deadline == "48")
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="resultTr2" style="background-color: #333" data-deadline="48" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">

        <td><p>Что-то</p></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="resultTr2" style="background-color: #333" data-deadline="47" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">

        <td><p>Что-то еще</p></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит и если истина?)

```css
.resultTr2 {
  background-color: #333;
}

tr[data-deadline="48"] {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<table><thead><tbody>
  <tr class="resultTr2" data-deadline="48" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">      
    
  <td> <p>Что-то</p>                                                   </td>
        
 </tr>
  <tr class="resultTr2" data-deadline="49" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">      
    
  <td> <p>Что-то 2</p>                                                   </td>
        
 </tr>
    <tr class="resultTr2" data-deadline="47" data-deadline-max="48" data-availability="500">      
    
  <td> <p>Что-то 3</p>                                                   </td>
        
 </tr>
</tbody></thead></table>
```

Comment: "Что значит ... истина?" - о-о-о, это глубокий философский вопрос. Тот, кто поставил нам минусы, наверняка тоже так думает.